# React: pass DOM element properties to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that looks as follows:

```
export default class WebGLCanvas extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="canvas-container">
        <Renderer></Renderer>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

However, in order to instance the `<Renderer>` component, I need to provide it a width and a height property, which will only be defined after the `.canvas-container` is instanced.

What is the appropriate way to pass DOM element properties to child components?

Answer (score 5):

I guess you are trying to implement a `Renderer` which will need height and width to calculate the dimensions for its child events:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {height: 0, width: 0};
}

componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.resetDimensions);
  this.resetDimensions();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resetDimensions);
}

resetDimensions() {
  var canvasContainer = this.refs.canvasContainer;
  this.setState({width: canvasContainer.clientWidth, height: canvasContainer.clientHeight});
}
```

The above code basically, sets a `height` and `width` as state to your WebGLCanvas component.

Using this you can pass the height and width to the Renderer component as props, like:

```
return (
    <div className="canvas-container" ref="canvasContainer">
      <Renderer height={this.state.height} width={this.state.width}></Renderer>
    </div>
)
```

I hope this helps.

P.S. The call to `getDOMNode` may or may not be required, depending on the React version.

Comment: For the one, who changed their mind, please add a comment if something was missing.

Comment: **refs** give me deprecated warning and is likely to be removed in one of the future releases.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to make the `canvas-container` its own component that passes the needed properties to its children component `<Renderer/>`. Something like:

Given code:

```
export default class WebGLCanvas extends Component {
  render() {
    return <CanvasContainer />; // use the canvas-container component
  }
}
```

Canvas container:

```
export default class CanvasContainer extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // initialize the state
    this.state = {
      width: 0,
      height: 0
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { width, height } = this.state;
    return <Renderer width={width} height={height}></Renderer>
  }
}
```

And wherever you set `width` and `height` in `CanvasContainer`, you set them through the state:

```
this.setState({ width, height });
```

which will re-render the `Renderer` component and pass these into its `props`

Comment: You still haven't solved the issue of getting the width and height of the canvas-container.

Comment: That wasn't an issue. The OP explained that he already defines that somewhere, I just explained he should set it through the component state and pass it through props.

Comment: I don't think the OP ever mentions having the `height` and `width` anywhere.

Comment: OP says that he needs to "*provide it a width and a height property, which will only be defined after the .canvas-container is instanced.*". OP's question is "*What is the appropriate way to pass DOM element properties to child components?*" not how/when to obtain properties. Your answer covers both so it should be the accepted answer but giving me a -1 for not going beyond the question isn't a good usage of downvoting :)

Comment: You make a fair point. I mis-judged. I can't take off my downvote unless you edit your answer. :(